# NG-Show if array contains a certain value and not another

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I have an 3 user rights - Admin, User, and Editor.  The way this is setup is:

If you are an `Admin` the return is `roles: ["Admin", "User", "Editor"]`

If you are an `User` the return is `roles: ["User"]`

If you are an `Editor` the return is `roles: ["User", "Editor"]`

Now what I have now is `ng-show="object.roles.length < 2" = User` and etc. for the other two.

I am sure there is a better/smarter way to do this or maybe it is easier to do it this way.  I am just not sure how to go about it differently.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve exactly? When do you want the element to be shown?

Comment: When loading your objects, compute and add `isAdmin`, `isUser`, `isEditor` properties.  Or if the roles can be changed at runtime, turn them into `$scope` functions.

Comment: @JBNizet - I am trying to hide/show contain specifically for the roles.  A quick example:

`User` = `<div ng-show="user">Hi User</div>`
`Admin` = `<div ng-show="admin">Hi Admin</div>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a good idea. You are managing your app's UI by counting an array length. What if this changes? I would suggest to verify always if the role needed is owned. For example `ng-show="hasRole('User')"`

```
$scope.hasRole = function(role){
     var indexOfRole = $scope.roles.indexOf(role); // or whatever your object is instead of $scope.roles
     if (indexOfRole === -1)
          return false;
     else
          return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div ng-show="roles.indexOf('Admin') >= 0"
```

Or, to be cleaner, delegate to a scope function:

```
<div ng-show="hasRole('Admin')"
```

and

```
$scope.hasRole = function(roleName) {
    return roles.indexOf(roleName) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: I have just seen your answer, we suggested almost the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="lil" ng-show="role.rileName.includes('someother') == 0 && role.rileName.includes('Admin')">
    <a class="{{role.rileName}}" href="javascript:void(0);" title="{{role.rileName}}" ng-controller="sampleRequestController" ng-click="addSamples(role.rileID,items.CanOrder);">{{role.rileName}}</a>
</li>
```

It will not show `if == 0`, otherwise it will.