# Angular ng-show if in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat for article comments, that looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          <li class="item" ng-class-even="'even'">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <i class="icon ion-person"></i> {{ comment.user.first_name }} {{ comment.user.last_name }}
                <i class="icon ion-record"></i> {{ comment.created_at }}
              </div>
              <!-- TODO: this needs to be an ng-if admin -->
              <div ng-show="hasRole(comment.user)" class="col right">
                <i class="icon ion-record admin"></i> Admin
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
```

I am trying to show this part only if the user is an admin:

```
<div ng-show="hasRole(comment.user)" class="col right">
                <i class="icon ion-record admin"></i> Admin
              </div>
```

I have tried to set that up following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047519/ng-show-if-array-contains-a-certain-value-and-not-another).

So I made a function in my controller:

```
 $scope.hasRole = function(roleName) {
    return $scope.comments.user.roles.indexOf(roleName) >= 0;
  }
```

But it returns -1 every time, even when the user is an admin. My data looks like this:

```
1:Object
    $$hashKey: "object:28"
    article_id:"2"
    created_at:"2016-05-12 12:19:05"
    id:6
    text:"someCommentText"
    updated_at:null
    user:Object
        active:"1"
        created_at:null
        first_name:"admin"
        id:1
        last_name:"admin"
        roles:Array[1]
            0:Object
            created_at:null
            id:1
            name:"Admin"
            parent_id:null
            pivot:Object
            slug:"admin"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your HTML

```
<div ng-show="hasAdminRole(comment.user.roles)" class="col right">
    <i class="icon ion-record admin"></i> Admin
</div>
```

this is the method to determine that the user belongs to the admin role or not.

```
$scope.hasAdminRole = function(roles) {
    var isAdmin = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        if (roles[i].name == 'Admin') {
            isAdmin = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isAdmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have an error on this line?

```
var indexOfRole = $scope.comments.indexOf(user.roles);
```

You are looking here to see if the list of roles for this users exists within the array of comments.

Maybe you need to just check in the actual `user.roles` array and see if there is an Admin role there? Something like:

```
$scope.hasRole = function(user) {
  for (var i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i++) {
    if (user.roles[i].slug === 'admin') { return true; }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's an object, you can fetch the index of only array. In the link that you provided is an array.